# How to put Google Store on Chinese Samsung Note10+

Tags: samsung, vpn

I'm currently living in China and decided to buy the Samsung Note10+ (has Android 9 installed) (had an iPhone from America beforehand), I did not know the headache that awaited me. I know no Chinese (Mandarin) and I can't keep asking my Chinese relatives for translations on my phone, so while I set the phone's system language to English, I still have no access to Google services at all.

I had tried installing Google Play store (ver. 17.5.16), Google Play Services (ver. 19.8.29), and Google Account Manager (ver. 6.0.1) from the AndroidAPKsBox site (used this site since apkmirror and other apk sites are blocked), all apks installed EXCEPT for Google Play Services which says the app did not install but with no error code. Is this the incorrect Services apk that I need?

Right now, VPNs are being blocked, even ExpressVPN so I'm not able to visit a lot of other helpful sites except this one. I know Google Play can't be fully utilized until the VPN starts working but I wanted to at least have all that I need on my phone so I can start using Google Play right away when available.

Edit: I just realized that there are a lot of differnt variants of Services that have different architecture and screen DPI. My Note has a Qualcomm so I assume I should choose the download that's made for ARMx64 chips with nodpi, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I found a Google Play Services for Arm64 nodpi download [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-19-8-29-release/google-play-services-19-8-29-040400-282600551-android-apk-download/), I installed it along with my current Google Play store and Google profile manager and now I'm able to download Google Play store apps without issue. The biggest obstacle was getting the right Google Play Services download.

For anyone else in the same position, APK Mirror is a Godsend as long as you know which version you need ([this article helped greatly](https://www.howtogeek.com/339665/how-to-find-your-android-devices-info-for-correct-apk-downloads/)) and make sure you download the compatible gapps.